# Apache rewrite root to subdirectory and keeping the request_uri

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite a URL such as `https://example.com/abcde` to `https://example.com/en/abcde` and `https://example.com/acefr` to `https://example.com/en/acefr`.

I have tried something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /en [R=301]
```

It can redirect me from `https://example.com/` to `https://example.com/en/`; but it fails when my URL is `https://example.com/abcde`, keeping the original URL.

What should I write in the config file?

Many thanks!

**UPDATE 1:**
I have probably missed to state that there are other subdirectories under the root and I still need to keep access, such as `https://example.com/zh/` and `https://example.com/hub/`.

Lastly, I don't want to keep the URL unchanged. I need it to be changed as well. I don't mind to use 'RedirectMatch' rule.

For better understanding:

```
https://example.com/abcde  ==> https://example.com/en/abcde
https://example.com/zh/abcde  #KEEP!  (in which subdirectory "zh/" exists)
https://example.com/en/ffsd  #KEEP!  (in which subdirectory "en/" exists)
https://example.com/hub/iyukmyjnrtb  #KEEP! (in which subdirectory "hub/" exists)
```

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE 2:**
Sorry for any misunderstanding. I also need the redirection for the following:

```
https://example.com/abcde/edgs  ==> https://example.com/en/abcde/edgs (in which subdirectory "abcde/" does not exists)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!en/)([^/]+/)?.*$ /en/$0 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.

Here is an explanation of each line of this rule:

```
# if this request is not for an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# if this request is not for an existing directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# if $1 is empty
RewriteCond $1 ^$ [OR]

# if $1 is not an existing file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d

# (?!en/) is a negative lookahead to assert we don't already have /en/ at start
# ([^/]+/)? captures an optional match before first / into $1
# $0 represents full match here that is between ^ and $
# /en/$0 prefixes /en/ before current Request URI
RewriteRule ^(?!en/)([^/]+/)?.*$ /en/$0 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: I have probably missed to state that there are other subdirectories under the root and I still need to keep access, such as `https://example.com/zh/` and `https://example.com/hub/`.

Moreover the rule you suggested leads to the redirect loop.

Lastly, I don't want to keep the URL unchanged. I need it to be changed as well. I don't mind to use 'RedirectMatch' rule.

Comment: Sorry my mistake again. Could you please rewrite the rule so that it also redirects if the subdirectory does not exist? (See my question updates above.) Thanks!

Comment: That's done my day! Many thanks! Lastly, a few more questions: 1. What does "$0" here represent? I had never used it except "$1". 2. Could you explain a bit what the regex does here? Thanks!

Comment: I have added explanation in my rule.